# slick effect using CSS on hover

Tags: sass, less, css

I've found this nice slick effect in here - http://www.red-team-design.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/04/css3-box-shadow.html.

Here is a copy of this - http://jsfiddle.net/cyvvilek/cL7x6/3/

I was wondering if there is any way to get this effect on hover.
Together with some CSS animation would give a nice effect, I think. 
There is a heavy use of :after and :before in CSS so it cannot be #box:after:hover or anything like that :)
I've heard about possibility of nesting stuff in SASS or LESS.. 
Can this be done with CSS alone?

Thx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, pseudo elements like :after and :before cannot be transitioned yet. SASS and LESS compile down to CSS, so everything technically possible with SASS or LESS, is possible with plain CSS.

What you can do is have a seperate element (maybe div) with the top shadow and fade it in and out on hover. Alternatively you can use an image.

Comment: So basically JavaScript or image... It's bad that CSS doesn't have any option like: #div1:hover {#div2:(visibility:hidden)} to do something with one element when you are hovering over another..:/   thanks

Comment: CSS does have that functionality - no need for javascript. The problem with using pseudo elements like :after and :before is just that their properties can't be animated with transitions. If you use real elements like drale2k suggested, what you want is achievable with css only. Take a look -> http://jsfiddle.net/joplomacedo/cL7x6/8/

Comment: You can use `#box:hover` like you'd use any other selector: `#box > #box_child` targets `#box`'s child `#box_child`. `#box:hover > #box_child` targets `#box`'s child `#box_child` when `#box` is hovered. `#box1:hover + #box2` targets, in the same way, `#box1`s adjacent sibling `#box2` when `#box1` is hovered.

Comment: Hi guys, I'm glad you like the shadow effect. The thing is that generated content can be animated with CSS3 only on latest Firefox browsers. I just hope the other browsers will catch up sooner or later.